# Eclipse recognizes android device, but won't doesn't allow selection of it

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open the DDMS, it shows the device there.

[image: shows the device is there]

However, when I try to run my program, Eclipse opens the Android Device chooser.
The Android Device Chooser has nothing under it.
[image: picture of the error]
I'm running it on a mac.  I've tried installing the drivers for the phone.  I've enabled downloading from unknown sources and downloading from USB.

Adb confirms that it is there too.

The emulator runs fine.

Don't know if this will help or not, but on the phone, there are two notifications.  "Connected as a media device" and "USB debugging connected" That should be normal?

I've searched everywhere and I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: which device are you connecting? Check if it is asking to allow the access in that device when you try to run an APP

Comment: I am using the moto g

Comment: Did you check that : "Allow this " popup in motoG ?

Comment: THIS MIGHT NOT BE THE ANSWER. right click on your project and select run as > run configuration > go to the target tab and uncheck use this device for all future launches. Also there are various options try a few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover over the the menus (Serial number, AVD Name, etc) with the mouse.  It should turn into the arrow thing to allow you to resize it.  Click and resize it a bit.  The device will magically appear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that minimum SDK version of your application is not less than or equal to Android version of your device due to which you are not able to select the device to run your application. Please check it

Comment: The minimum SDK in the manifest is 8.  The target is 19.  The phone runs kitkat.

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging from Developer Options?

Comment: Yes, I've enabled usb debugging.